# DJANGO 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, request, wsgi

I get this error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get' in my code
Below is my function in views.py

```
def user_attendance(request):
   # Get the attendance records for the current user
    attendance_records = Attendance.objects.filter(user=request.user)
 
    # Create a form instance
    form = CompensationRequestForm()

   # Check if the form has been submitted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Bind the form with the POST data
        form = CompensationRequestForm(request.POST)
        # Check if the form is valid
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the form data
            form.save()
            # Redirect to the user_attendance view
           return redirect('user_attendance')
    context = {'attendance_records': attendance_records, 'form': form}

    # Render the template with the attendance records and form
    return render(request, 'user_attendance.html', context)
```

and below is my form in forms.py

```
class CompensationRequestForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField()
    reason = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    def save(self):
        # Save the form data to the database
        pass
```

how to fix this?
chatgpt didnt help, so i asked here

Comment: can you add the error stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

instead of this `form = CompensationRequestForm(request.POST)` try this way:

```
form = CompensationRequestForm(data=request.POST)
```

Comment: Still the same error  'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 0):

instead of
form = CompensationRequestForm(request.POST)
# Check if the form is valid

replace with

form = CompensationRequestForm(requests.POST)
# Check if the form is valid

Comment: But the argument is called `request`, not `requests`....

Comment: Actually the answer is ambiguous, you are suggesting to replace particular part of code with the same code as in the question. Please edit your answer and explain certain solution for questioner. Best regards.

Comment: yes, you are right. I will edit